# bash append file from multiple thread

Tags: multithreading, bash, thread-safety, gnu-parallel

I'm working on big data, I'm trying to parallelize my process functions.
I can use several threads and process every user is a different thread (I have 200k users).

Every thread should append the first `n` lines of a file that produce, in an output file, shared between all the threads.

I wrote a Java program that execute `head -n 256 thread_processed.txt >> output` (every thread will do this)

I need the output file to be wrote in an atomic way.

If the thread A wrote lines from 0 to 9 and threads B wrote lines from 10 to 19 the output should be: `[0...9 10... 19]`. Lines can't overlaps, it can't be something like `[0 1 2 17 18 3 4 ...]`

How I can manage concurrent write access to the output file in a bash script?

Comment: Your Java code needs to write the output of each thread to a separate file, so that another thread can concatenate them in the correct order. You don't need all the threads to complete to concatenate the output from the first `k` threads, but you do need the first `k` to complete.

Comment: Do a mega hack and use `sed` to write to a specific line  But sirioslly if you know how to order do as chepner suggested or prefix the lines with a number and sort them.

Comment: ps. or make the lines the same size and you'll be able to put them in the correct possitions easily from java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sem` from GNU Parallel should be able to do it:

```
sem --id mylock "head -n 256 thread_processed.txt >> output"
```

It will start a mutex named mylock.

If you are concerned that someone might read `output` while the `head` is running:

```
sem --id mylock "cp output o2; head -n 256 thread_processed.txt >> o2; mv o2 output"
```